# Georeference raster along a curve

Tags: python, gdal

I have bathymetry data for a river in numpy array format. Unfortunately, I do not have the coordinates for each value of this array, but only the central line where the boat passed (x2). I decided to draw a maximum line 100 meters after the boat's path (x1).

[image]

To georeference those I used xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax. Here is a part of the Python script

```
xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = [track.coords[-1][0],track.coords[-1][1],up.coords[0][0],up.coords[0][1]]
xres = (xmax-xmin)/float(ncols)
yres = (ymax-ymin)/float(nrows)
geotransform=(xmin,xres,0,ymax,0, -yres)   

output_raster = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create('/content/myraster.tif',ncols, nrows, 1 ,gdal.GDT_Float32)  # Open the file
output_raster.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)  # Specify its coordinates
srs = osr.SpatialReference()                 # Establish its coordinate encoding
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)                     # This one specifies WGS84 lat long.
output_raster.SetProjection( srs.ExportToWkt() )   # Exports the coordinate system 
output_raster.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(np_chan1)   # Writes my array to the raster
output_raster.FlushCache()
```

With that I managed to geo-reference, but the river curve was ignored. Would like to know how to do to consider this curve of the boat.
[image]

Comment: Geotransform seems to only do Affine transformations i.e no 'bending'
https://gdal.org/tutorials/geotransforms_tut.html
You might want to try GDAL Warp with GCPs, here is an exmaple:
https://kokoalberti.com/articles/georeferencing-and-digitizing-old-maps-with-gdal/

Comment: Is it possible to do this in a numpy array?